# Styling a checkbox without the label tag

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

I made a checkbox style and it uses the label tag. See below

Is it possible to still have the CSS of the entire checkbox without the label tag? So i just have the Input tag, but still the CSS.
Here is the CSS of the checkbox.

```css
.control {
font-size: 18px;
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.control input {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: 0;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
background: #ccc;
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
background: orange;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus ~ .control__indicator {
background: #ecb53a;
}

.control input:disabled ~ .control__indicator {
pointer-events: none;
opacity: .6;
background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control__indicator:after {
position: absolute;
display: none;
content: '';
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
display: block;
}

.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
top: 4px;
left: 8px;
width: 3px;
height: 8px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
border: solid black;
border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="control control--checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Have you tried it without the label tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What im asking is if i can still have the style of the checkbox its having WITH the label tags, WITHOUT the label tags.

Comment: If you want only css solution i think you can't because if you click on `<div class="control__indicator"></div>` you don't select checkbox. With for inside label you can click and activate checkbox.

Comment: I just want `<input type="checkbox"/>` With an class and still have the CSS its having now.

Comment: IS THERE ANY WAY TO ADD A CUSTOM indeterminate FOR THE CHECKBOX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

===================================================================

## Css solution (will work in the Chrome, not in FF, IE)

You can apply custom style to the checkbox using css `:after` , `:checked`.

Please see below code or jsfiddle

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

CSS

```
    input[type='checkbox']:after{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: rgb(224,224,224);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #00ff00;
}
```

FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/evfr3kk3/

Hope this will help you to apply your checkbox custom styling.

===================================================================

## NEW UPDATED :: Cross browser solution with jQuery

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

CSS

```
.custom-checkbox{
  line-height: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right: -18px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: rgb(224,224,224);
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.custom-checkbox.checked{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 3px solid #00ff00;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin: 0px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 19px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

JS

```
function setCheckbox(elem){
        if($(elem).is(':checked')){
         $(elem).prev('.custom-checkbox').addClass('checked');
    }else{
       $(elem).prev('.custom-checkbox').removeClass('checked');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        // apply custom checkbox on page ready
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').before('<span class="custom-checkbox">');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
          setCheckbox($(this));
        });
});

// on input change, change custom checkbox 
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
          setCheckbox($(this));
    });
```

FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/2rsa7ghn/48/

Comment: Just for my information, if the answer is accepted, then Why downvote?

Comment: the "after" pseudo class does not work well with input elements in Firefox and IE

Comment: Great, its working fine in chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: @dineshkashera  - Thanks, I have updated my answer for cross browser solution. Hope it will be help someone.

Answer (score 3):

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  top: 2px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 22px; 
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid #35ac19;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #35ac19;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
input[type=checkbox]:before {
   content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    z-index: 0;
    border: 2px solid #A9ABAE;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -o-transition: .2s;
    -ms-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s;
       background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" >
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/chandan20j/myr2fe13/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for some browsers!

**CSS**

```
input[type='checkbox']:after {
line-height: 1.5em;
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
background: rgb(224,224,224);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
content: '✔';
text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

It looks nice, you can customize it!